# unresolved external symbol (C++, glewBufferData, LNK2001)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, opengl, linker

I'm using VS2010 and I was able to compile a program with an empty white window but then when I tried to create buffer and texture objects I get these linker errors.

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferData
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindBuffer
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers
```

I've double checked that my include directories have the path to glew and freeglut's include folders. I've also  made sure that the it's library folders are set under Additional Library Directories and Additional Dependencies have freeglut.lib, glew32.lib, opengl32.lib.

I also added "GLEW_STATIC" to Processor Definitions

I've placed the glew32.dll and freeglut.dll into the same folder as the exe files.

I've tried adding this line

```
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
```

as well as

```
#define GLEW_STATIC 1
```

but no combination of any of them has worked. Someone please help! I really don't know what else to do.

This is what my code looks like now.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/wglew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include <iostream>

#include "util.h"

static struct {
    GLuint vertex_buffer, element_buffer;
    GLuint textures[2];

    // Shader objects go here
} gl_resources;

static GLuint make_buffer( GLenum target, const void *buffer_data,
        GLsizei buffer_size){
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer); // Creates the object name.
    glBindBuffer(target, buffer); // Binds the object name to the target.

    // Allocates the buffer.
    glBufferData(target, buffer_size, buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    return buffer;
}

static const GLfloat gl_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f,  -1.0f,  // bottom left
     1.0f,  -1.0f,  // bottom right
    -1.0f,   1.0f,  // top left
     1.0f,   1.0f   // top right
};

static const GLushort gl_element_buffer_data[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

static GLuint make_texture(const char *filename){
    GLuint texture;
    int width, height;
    void *pixels = read_tga(filename, &width, &height);

    if (!pixels)
        return 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture); // Creates a texture object.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); // our texture object to a 2D target.

    // Setting texture parameters.
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,     GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,     GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // Allocating textures
    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,           // target, level of detail
        GL_RGB8,                    // internal format
        width, height, 0,           //  width, height, border
        GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,   // external format, type
        pixels                      // pixels
    );

    free(pixels);
    return texture;

}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

static int make_resources(void){
    // Making Buffers
    gl_resources.vertex_buffer = make_buffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
        gl_vertex_buffer_data, sizeof(gl_vertex_buffer_data));
    gl_resources.element_buffer = make_buffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        gl_element_buffer_data, sizeof(gl_element_buffer_data));

    // Making textures
    gl_resources.textures[0] = make_texture("hello1.tga");
    gl_resources.textures[1] = make_texture("hello2.tga");

    if(gl_resources.textures[0] == 0 || gl_resources.textures[1] == 0)
        return 0;

    // Making shaders
    return 1;
}

static void update_fade_factor(void){ // Update

}

static void render(void){
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Sets the Clear colour to white.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // fills the buffer with the Clear colour.
    glutSwapBuffers(); // Brings the cleared buffer to the screen.
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE); // Double for smoother render
    glutInitWindowSize(400,300);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello World");
    glutDisplayFunc(&render);
    glutIdleFunc(&update_fade_factor);

    if(!make_resources()){
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to load resources\n");
        return 1;
    }

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: should be a matter of adding `-lglew32` to the lib options - search for vs2010 add library to linkpath

Comment: @amdixon I've added the path to the lib file under Additional Library Dependencies and I've also added it under Input

Comment: Try swapping the headers include order, freeglut before.

Comment: C or C++? If C do not `#include` `<iostream>`.

Comment: @amdixon: No it shouldn't. That is the dynamic linking library, `glew32s` is the static library.

Comment: @concept3d When I swapped the order, it gave me this error 
`fatal error C1189: #error :  gl.h included before glew.h`

@alk I tried but it didn't make a difference

Comment: @EssDeCastro: Do not `#define GLEW_STATIC` if you link to `glew32`. That is the DLL version of the library. If you `#define GLEW_STATIC`, you need to link to `glew32s`. I would suggest you use the static library to be honest, but you have to link to the proper library. You are mixing-and-matching pre-processor definitions with the wrong library at the moment.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman The glew32 and glew32s is in the same folder so I just changed the additional dependancies in input to glew32s.lib instead of glew32.lib, then I removed `GLEW_STATIC` from processor definitions and re-added `#define GLEW_STATIC` into the code but it's still giving me that error. I don't know what else to do =[